# why $m^*(A)\leq m^*(A \cap E^c) + m^*(A\cap E)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Each time I see a proof that a set $E$ is measurable, the proof is divided into two: one part shows why for any set $A$: $m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap E^c)+ m^*(A \cap E)$, and the other part states that the other why around is trivial and so we get that $m^*(A) =  m^*(A \cap  E^c) + m^*(A\cap E)$ and thus $E$ is indeed measurable, but I don't understand why is that true?

Is it because of the definition of $m^*$ as the $\inf \{ \sum_k |I_k| \colon  E \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k\}$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Subadditivity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
 m^*(A)
= m^*((A \cap E) \cup (A \cap E^C))
\leq m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^C)
$$
by the (finite) subadditivity of the outer measure $m^*$.

Comment: I saw earlier a proof for $$
 m^*(E)
\leq \sum En | E = \cup En
$$. Is it the same thing?

Comment: One of the axioms of an outer measure is that $m^*(\emptyset) = 0$, another one is that $m^*(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} m^*(A_n)$ for every countable collection $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of subsets $A_n$. From this we get the finite subadditivity $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A \cup B \cup \emptyset \cup \dotso) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B) + m^*(\emptyset) + \dotso = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$ for all subsets $A$ and $B$.